# including checkboxes to data output by foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have some images url in `mysql` database which I have successfully retrieved and displayed the images on my wordpress admin page using a `foreach` loop like so;

```
$images = $wpdb->get_results( 
    "SELECT * 
        FROM $prod_table
        WHERE name='animal'"
);

foreach ( $images as $image) 
{
    echo '<img src="'.$image->image_url.'"/>;
}
```

This works fine in getting displaying the images, but i would also like to add a checkbox next to each image so that i can decide to check images that will display on my homepage.

I have tried this, but it ends up checking all the images.

```
$images = $wpdb->get_results( 
        "SELECT * 
            FROM $prod_table
            WHERE name='animal'"
    );

    foreach ( $images as $image) 
    {
        echo '<img src="'.$image->image_url.'"/>;
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="options[checked_img]" value="1" <?php checked( $options['checked_img'], 1 ); ?>';
    }
```

When one of  these is checked, it selects all of them. So how can I uniquely check them?

thanks,
Ronny.

Comment: All checkboxes has the same name `name="options[checked_img]"`, add unique name to each

Comment: Yes.. i know, that why I need to know how to uniquely check them.

Comment: `name="options[checked_img]"` --> `name="options['.$image->id.']"`or something similar

Comment: Or just use empty brackets? `name="options[]"`

Comment: @RainFromHeaven, but then he can't identify the checkboxes after the `POST`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have a `<?php ?>` tag when you're already inside a PHP tag?
You're forgetting to close your image string that you're echoing.
You're using the same name for all your inputs.

Aside from that, you should keep it simple.
I'm assuming that "checked(...)" is a custom function that determines whether the image should be checked or not.

```php
$images = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $prod_table WHERE name='animal'");  

foreach ( $images as $key => $image) 
{
    if(checked($options['checked_img'], $key))
        $is_checked = "checked='checked'";
    else 
        $is_checked = "";

    echo "<img src='{$image->image_url}' />";
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='options[$key]' value='1' $is_checked />";
}
```